# How do I approve a smart contract to spend my ERC20 tokens?

Tags: erc-20, erc-20-approve, allowance

My first time here, please forgive me for any mistakes.

I made a custom ERC20 token using Openzeppelin ERC20PresetFixedSupply.
I want to use that in my contract.
I was using this code to test how IERC20 approve and allowance work.

```
    constructor(IERC20 token) {
        _token = token;
    }
    
    IERC20 private _token;
    
    function ERC20Balance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function ERC20TotalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _token.totalSupply();
    }
    
    function ERC20Allowance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    }
    
    function ERC20Approve() external returns (bool) {
        return _token.approve(address(this), _token.balanceOf(msg.sender));
    }
```

This is the output I got after execution. I approved balanceOf(msg.sender) for the contract to spend but it shows contract has 0 allowance.

[image: Remix]

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Inside `ERC20Aprove()`, the caller of the `approve` function is the contract itself, not the transaction sender. So currently your contract is just approving itself.

Comment: Your user has to directly call the `approve` function on the ERC20 smart contrat : copy paste the ERC20 contract on Remix and call `approve` with your contract address as the `spender` parameter.

Comment: Okay, so the caller is the contract itself, got it. I'll try out your suggestions. Thanks.